# Can't get socket.io-client to run through browserify

Tags: javascript, socket.io

When i include socket.io using require('socket.io-client') it says it can't find it, then if I try just socket.io on the following line:

```
var clientSource = read(require.resolve('socket.io-client/socket.io.js'), 'utf-8');
```

on 'resolve(' I get the error: 'undefined is not a function'

My package.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.9.x",
    "react": "0.13.x",
    "react-async": "2.1.x",
    "react-timeago": "2.0.x",
    "react-router-component": "0.24.x",
    "superagent": "latest",
    "react-document-title": "1.0.x",
    "fibers": "^1.0.2",
    "underscore": "1.8.x",
    "http-proxy": "1.0.x",
    "feathers": "1.0.x",
    "socket.io": "1.3.x",
    "material-ui": "0.7.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "9.0.x",
    "grunt": "0.4.x",
    "grunt-browserify": "^3.5.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-nodemon": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-react": "^0.10.0"
  },
  "license": "GPL"
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that socket.io can just be included by a straight script tag into a browser?  You don't need browserify to run the browser-side client version of socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `socket.io-client` package separately from the `socket.io` package.

```
npm install --save socket.io-client
```

Comment: True.The one inside socket.io is for that module to use.